npm list show results using incorrect characters
I run npm list command in powershell (v. 7.4.4) or cmd.exe and I get the result in this way:
    npm -g list --depth=0
    C:\\Program Files\\nodejs -\> .\
    +-- @angular/cli@18.0.1
    +-- corepack@0.25.2
    +-- npm@10.5.0
    \`-- nx@19.4.0

but if I run the same command in VS Code the results use graphic characters:
    npm -g list --depth=0
    C:\\Program Files\\nodejs -\> .\
    ├── @angular/cli@18.0.1
    ├── corepack@0.25.2
    ├── npm@10.5.0
    └── nx@19.4.0

I'm using the same font in terminal and vs code, how can I set the terminal to get the same results of VS Code?

In cmd.exe.
Set the code page to UTF-8:
chcp 65001

Set the npm configuration to use Unicode:
set NPM_CONFIG_UNICODE=true

Now, run your npm list command:
npm -g list --depth=0



ABHI's helfpul cmd.exe solution applies analogously to PowerShell:
# Tell npm to use (non-ASCII) Unicode line-drawing characters
# and use UTF-8 to encode them.
$env:NPM_CONFIG_UNICODE = 1

# For *printing to the display*, the above is enough.
# However, if you want to *capture or redirect* the `npm list` output, 
# you must also tell PowerShell to decode external-program output as UTF-8.
# (Note that `chcp 65001` does *not* work, because .NET caches encodings.)
# You may want to save and restore the original value.
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()

# This will now use Unicode line-drawing characters.
npm -g list --depth=0

Note:

It's unclear to me why npm when running in Visual Studio's integrated terminal defaults to using Unicode line-drawing characters, in the absence of the $env:NPM_CONFIG_UNICODE environment variable.

Perhaps npm detects when it is running in this environment (perhaps via $env:TERM_PROGRAM equaling 'vscode').
You can, however, override the default, i.e. you can explicitly revert to ASCII characters with $env:NPM_CONFIG_UNICODE = 0


For more information on making a PowerShell console fully UTF-8 aware, see the bottom section of this answer.



Maybe I found out, in Visual Studio's integrated terminal it works because the terminal is loaded using this command: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe '-noexit' '-command' 'try { . "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\contrib\terminal\browser\media\shellintegration.ps1" } catch {}' (VS Code shows it if hovering on pwsh item).
In shellintegration.ps1 these is a __VSCode-Escape-Value function, it appears that characters are converted to unicode mode.
